# Problema com slick carrousel e modal do bootstrap

Tags: html

Olá, estou realizando um projeto para um cliente onde estou utilizando um modal do bootstrap e dentro desse modal tem um carrousel utilzando o slick carrousel, entretanto eu não ao certo o porque mas não está iniciando ao abrir o modal, tem clicar em algo para ele iniciar, alguém poderia me orientar em relação a isso?

P.S: Como são coisas pré prontas não consigo colocar o codigo aqui por que não sei ao certo em que ponto está com problema, mas eu estou um pouco desesperado pois preciso entregar esse projeto e nao consigo arrumar esse bug.

site slick-carrousel:http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Answer (score 2):

Vou tentar te ajudar mesmo sem ver seu codigo.

Se você estiver usando o modal do bootstrap ou dialog do jquery, vc tem um problema ao instanciar o slick, pois quando ele é instanciado antes do modal abrir, as referencias são diferentes e quando abre o modal, está tudo aparentemente errado, então vamos fazer um truque.
Depois que você chamar o metodo para abrir o modal, tente instanciar o slick ou dar um resize nele.

Exemplo

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('.my-slider').slick("setPosition", 0);
});
```

ou

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $('.my-slider').resize();
});
```

Segue um exemplo funcionando.
http://jsfiddle.net/vanduzled/nv446jgm/2/

Tente isso, se não der certo, envie o código e analisaremos juntos.